# LINQ Dynamically Select Column From Column Name

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, dynamic-linq

I made this query to get data from a table

```
List<MyTable> liDeatil = Db.Database.SqlQuery<MyTable>("SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[MyTable]").ToList();
```

From `liDetail` i want to select column dynamically such as

```
 liDeatil.Select(s => new myclass{ Id = s.Id ,Marks = ....}).Tolist();
```

Where MyClass is

```
 public class MyClass
 {
     public Nullable<decimal> Id { get; set; }
     public string Marks { get; set; }
     public string rank { get; set; }
 }
```

is there any way to get the column 
pls help me

I tried To do this by reflection But its not working

```
var ss = liDeatil.Select(s => new MyClass{ Id = s.Id ,Marks = s.GetType().GetProperties("ColumnMarks")}).Tolist();
```

**EDITED**

```
     public class MyTable
     {
         public Nullable<decimal> Id { get; set; }
         public string ColumnMarks{ get; set; }
         public string ColumnMarks1{ get; set; }
         public string ColumnMarks2{ get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "From liDetail i want to select column dynamically"?

Comment: in Select statement i want to select ColumnMarks From liDetail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what you are trying to achieve with reflection, below code should work:

```
var ss = liDeatil.Select(s => new MyClass{ Id = s.Id ,
Marks = (string)s.GetType().GetProperty("ColumnMarks").GetValue(s,null)}).Tolist();
```

Comment: I have edited my code, try with "GetProperty("ColumnMarks")" instead of "GetProperties("ColumnMarks")"

Answer (score 3):

What isn't working exactly? Are you getting an exception? I'm confused where you are getting "ColumnMarks" from. You didn't post the definition for MyTable, so maybe it is from there.

```
liDeatil.Select(s => new myclass{ Id = s.Id, Marks = (string)s.GetType().GetProperty("ColumnMarks").GetValue(s, null)}).Tolist();
```

Comment: i HAD EDITED MY QUESTION

Comment: This answer or Victor's below should work then. You need to call GetValue once you get the property via reflection.